# ANTLR4 Generating Lexer in JAVA instead of C Sharp

Tags: antlr4

When doing
java -cp C:\Tools\Libraries\antlr4-csharp-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool Hello.g4
I get the following files:

```
HelloBaseListener.cs
Hello.tokens
HelloListener.cs
HelloParser.cs
HelloLexer.tokens
HelloLexer.java
```

My question is about the last file. Why is it .java instead of .cs?
I'm using antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar

Grammar is:

```
grammar Hello; // Define a grammar called Hello
options
{
    language=CSharp_v4_0;   
}


r : 'hello' ID ; // match keyword hello followed by an identifier
ID : [a-z]+ ; // match lower-case identifiers
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines, \r (Windows)
```

Hello Sam! I only have visual studio express so I can't install the extension. This is the code that I'm using but it is still generating the HelloLexer.java.

```
AntlrClassGenerationTaskInternal a = new AntlrClassGenerationTaskInternal();
List<String> files = new List<string>();
files.Add(@"C:\Tools\Grammars\Hello.g4");
a.JavaVendor = "JavaSoft";
a.ToolPath = @"C:\Tools\Libraries\antlr4-csharp-complete.jar";
a.JavaInstallation = "Java Development Kit";
a.SourceCodeFiles = files;
a.OutputPath = @"C:\Tools\Grammars\CSharp\";

a.Execute();
```

By the way, visual studio complained because it was not able to find Antlr4ClassGenerationTask.IsFatalException(ex)

I appreciate your help on this.

Regards,
Omar.

Comment: Is it just a file naming issue? (Does HelloLexer.java contain Java or C# code?)

Comment: Java code. You can see "imports" "extends".

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 11/20/13: Updated instructions are now available on the project wiki**

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/wiki/Installation

---

Here are a few messages I sent over the past few months related to this issue. If you don't want to install the Visual Studio extension described below, you'll need to use the source code of [`Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal.cs`](https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4BuildTasks/Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal.cs) to determine a set of command line options that will work.

Also, you can remove the `language=CSharp_v4_0;` option because it's passed on the command line now.

---

The C# target wasn't designed for command line usage. You will need to integrate the code generation into your project file according to the instructions on the following page, and the parsers will be generated automatically when you build your project.

https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs

---

You do need to include the .g4 file in your project and configure a few properties of the file. If you install the following extension before adding the grammar to your project, all the other options will be configured for you automatically.
[ANTLR Language Support for Visual Studio 2010-
2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/25b991db-befd-441b-b23b-bb5f8d07ee9f)

If you already have the .g4 file in your project, and want to still use the extension to automatically configure the proper settings, you can do the following:

1. Install the extension.
2. Click the project in Solution Explorer and enable Show All Files (button on the Solution Explorer toolbar). This step greatly simplifies step 4.
3. Right click the .g4 file in the project, and select Exclude From Project.
4. Right click the .g4 file again and select Include In Project.
5. (Optional) You can disable Show All Files when you no longer need it.

Comment: The code in `Antlr4ClassGenerationTaskInternal` launches a new command line process (`java.exe`) with arguments. The code in that file is not meant to be called by other code, but instead you can use it as a reference to figure out what the command line options are.

Comment: The updated instructions work great, as long as you've properly cleaned up any changes made under your other instructions in the Readme file on github.  You will probably want to update that file.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug, I had got the same problem, but there is a solution.

1) If you want you can remove

```
options
{
    language=CSharp_v4_0;   
}
```

I think is ignored by the code generator

2) create a BAT file with the follow code

```
@echo OFF
IF "%CLASSPATH%" == "" (SET CLASSPATH=.;.\antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar;%CLASSPATH%)
java org.antlr.v4.Tool %* -Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5
```

put antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar in the same path, now you can use this file to comile. To resolve the issue the magic command line argument is "-Dlanguage=CSharp_v4_5" or the version of C# you are using.

The generated files now have inside the Lexer.cs

Comment: Thank you.  I spent a while trying to convert the generated `_serializedATN` variable from Java to C# with no success.  This saved the day!

Comment: @JonSenchyna I ***strongly*** recommend you do not follow this post. The C# target is specifically designed for integration with your project build, and choosing another approach will significantly impact the reliability of your builds. The instructions for properly installing the C# target of ANTLR 4 can be found here: https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs/wiki/Installation

Comment: I have tried following your instructions in that link to the letter, and I get an error message stating `The "JavaVendor" parameter is not supported by the "Antlr4ClassGenerationTask" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property.`

Comment: I have fixed the issue.  I had some leftover information (sepcifically `<Antlr4BuildTaskPath>` and `<Antlr4ToolPath>` nodes) in my project file from your instructions in the README file on github: https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs